# Error loading xml locally on Chrome browser

Tags: xml, google-chrome

I am working on a project which is xml based and is supposed to run locally and online.

There are several xml files which have to be loaded page by page. All works fine if the content is run online or using localhost.

The problem comes when the content is run locally Chrome simply fails to load the xml IE and Firefox works fine. I searched all over the net but could not find any solution to this problem.

Here is the sample to replicate the problem
http://www.exzip.com/download/K6VLSYCB

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explains and it seems there is no solution to this

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416
http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html